# ExceptionHandler Controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the below method in the controller, asserting the test using WebMvcTest for bad requests and it works fine but the below lines are not covered in the test coverage. How to cover the below lines?

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public ModelAndView illegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException e)
  {
    LOG.error("{}: {}", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("400");
    mav.addObject("exception", e);
    return mav;
  }
}
```